# Get local price for IAP using MKStoreKit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am using MKStoreKit for IAP. I can get all the task done easily (it's simple and easy to use) but m stuck to get the local price by productid

Is it possible to get the local price in mkstorekit ?

And if i will display local price for product will it create any problem in review ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//...
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest start];
//...

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct *product in skProducts) {
       NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
       [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
       [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
       [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
       NSString *formattedPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
       //Use formattedPrice

    }
}
```

---

EDIT

If you are using: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSKProductsAvailableNotification:) name:kMKStoreKitProductsAvailableNotification object:nil];
[[MKStoreKit sharedKit] startProductRequest];
//...

- (void)handleSKProductsAvailableNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSArray * skProducts = [MKStoreKit sharedKit].availableProducts; 
    for (SKProduct *product in skProducts) {
       NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
       [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
       [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
       [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
       NSString *formattedPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
       //Use formattedPrice

    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing ... instead of this for loop for array i just want to get price for single product , i m having product id

Comment: Well, you can collect products' formatted prices in a dictionary, like dic = @{product1.productIdentifier : product1Price, product2.productIdentifier : product2Price, ...} , and get price of single product by dic[productID]

Answer (score 0):

MKStoreKit has built in ability to display product titles along with their localized price.

It has function to format the product name with their localized name, description and currency.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) purchasableObjectsDescription;
```

For more details you can refer: [MKStoreKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/)

Comment: Are you implementing this method for SKProduct : - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
        (SKProductsResponse *)response{}; the response will give you all product list with its price and other details.

Comment: ok. so it will give you all products in array self.availableProducts which contains all details of product including price.